# Does every node module support in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm naive to Node and angular so as I do have one doubt.
Does all modules written in node can be install in angular project or is there special thing required?

Specifically I am looking of this "npm install --save upstox" library with angular.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages#support-packages

Comment: Link shows basic node required packages. At any point i need all those mention packages. But my question is that other packages can be used?

Comment: I don;t think so

Comment: AFAIK i think you can you might need to makesome modification on how the data is transmitted but you can